# Compare electromagnets and solenoids

Tags: inductance

Okay, so I have to write a research paper in science, and it wanted me to compare them. When I tried to research the subject, I found nothing but people who contrasted the two. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference is an electromagnet is a coil of copper wound on a solid metallic core that becomes a magnetic when the coil is energized, whereas a solenoid is basically an electromagnet with a hollow core where a metal plunger is located. The movement of the metal plunger when the solenoid is energized can operate an external device, such as a valve.

So while an electromagnetic simply creates a magnet, a solenoid converts electrical energy into some form of mechanical energy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The term solenoid often refers to just the coil of wire (usually copper coated with an insulating varnish).  It may or may not activate a plunger.

Comment: Well it all depends on our individual experience. In my work testing electrical products solenoids performed mechanical tasks. In any case its the mechanical feature that, to me, that differentiates a solenoid from a basic electromagnet.